# Azure SDK for .Net, Set timeout for SendMessageAsyn function

Tags: c#, .net, azure, message-queue

I am using Azure SDK for .Net to send messages to message queue. The code looks like

```
ServiceBusSender _serviceBusSender ....
..
serviceBusSender.SendMessageAsync(new ServiceBusMessage("Hello")).Wait();
```

After sending operation I am waiting to get this operation. It might be possible that send message operation can take more than 2 seconds. I want to set the timeout here, if SendMessageAsync() method take more than 1 second then I want the code to throught timeout excetion. I am not able to find the option in the documentation.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.messaging.servicebus.servicebussender.sendmessageasync?view=azure-dotnet

Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: Have you considered passing a cancellation token into that method from a `CancellationTokenSource` with the [`CancelAfter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.cancellationtokensource.cancelafter?view=net-8.0#system-threading-cancellationtokensource-cancelafter(system-timespan)) property set to 1 second?

Comment: Also, why are you calling `Wait()` on the task returned by `SendMessageAsync` instead of using `await`?

Comment: I am using this method in synchronous API method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SendMessageAsync` takes a cancellation token as a second parameter. This means you can generate a cancellation token that cancels after a specified amount of time.

```cs
var cancellationToken = new CancellationTokenSource(1000).Token;

serviceBusSender.SendMessageAsync(new ServiceBusMessage("Hello"), cancellationToken).Wait();
```

This will throw a `TaskCancelledException` when the timeout occurs, which you can catch and rethrow as the desired type if needed.